# How to install nodejs 19 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04

I downloaded and extracted `node-v19.8.1-linux-x64.tar.xz` on my computer, but the README file contain no info about the download and the instructions of ChatGPT aren't working. So I hope someone here can help me.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't made me touch to my system so it's ok on this point

Comment: You need to ask where you got it from. If there is no readme the only thing to do is to start the executable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312642/how-to-install-node-tar-xz-file-in-linux  has a clear how to so why not use that?

Comment: @Rinzwind because ChatGPT gave them bad info.  They don't need to install-from-source, Node provides APT repos for Ubuntu.  Basically, ChatGPT 75% of the time gives absolutely crap answers and should NOT be consulted first for issues.  :P

Comment: The official instructions are here, just follow this:
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ChatGPT is **not** a reliable source to solve issues.  In many many cases the AI gives you **broken answers**.  In fact, in most cases, you are better off asking your question here or searching Google and bypassing ChatGPT completely and getting help here.

The proper way to set up NodeJS and such on Ubuntu is fairly easy.  Both **[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04)** and **[Linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-22-04/)** have good guides for installing NodeJS on Ubuntu 22.04, but in principle this is the process for installing the latest supported version(s) of NodeJS:

**Use NodeSource archives for a latest release of Node**

1. Download the setup script.

   ```
   cd ~
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
   ```

   Replace `19.x` with the specific major version of NODE you're looking to install - 19 is the current latest as of this post being written.
2. Execute the setup script

   ```
   sudo bash ~/nodesource_setup.sh
   ```
3. Once the script is done running, install via APT.

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install nodejs
   ```

That will set up Node and NPM on your system.

**Note that this is specifically for supported Ubuntu releases, and may not immediately work with newer Ubuntu releases which have just come out, because these repositories and this mechanism are a NodeSource approach/solution and they are not immediately up to date with newer Ubuntu releases as they come out.**

Comment: This still works, but `nodesource_setup.sh` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

I used [snap](https://snapcraft.io/node) - green `Install` button at top right.

Or install it from the command line, where in `--channel=19` you replace `19` with the version you want:

```
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=19
```